# How to append dict to a list in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a temp dictionary in each loop and then put it in a list so I can have a list of dicts. Here is the code:

```
dicts=[]
tempdic={}
for i in range(0, len(self.info)):
    tempdic.clear()
    tempdic['title']=str(self.info[i]['title'])
    tempdic['desc']=str(self.info[i]['desc'])
    dicts.append(tempdic)
```

The problem is, when I change the tempdic in each loop, the contents of `dicts` (list) also changes with that so that, at the end, I have a list with several dicts that all have the same contents.

Comment: `dicts` is a bad variable name for a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resetting the same `dict` object in the loop, and adding reference to it in the list. You need to create new `dict` object on each iteration:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.info)):
    tempdic = dict()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move this line:

```
tempdic={}
```

inside the loop:

```
dicts=[]
for i in range(0, len(self.info)):
    tempdic={}
    tempdic['title']=str(self.info[i]['title'])
    tempdic['desc']=str(self.info[i]['desc'])
    dicts.append(tempdic)
```

That way, a new dictionary is created with each iteration of the loop.  Also, notice that I removed `tempdic.clear()`, since it is no longer needed.

Actually, this job can be done a lot simpler like so:

```
dicts=[]
for i in range(0, len(self.info)):
    dicts.append({'title':str(self.info[i]['title']), 'desc':str(self.info[i]['desc'])})
```

As you can see, there isn't actually a need to make `tempdic`.

Comment: @Downvoter - Why the downvote?  Did you find something wrong with my post?  If so, please let me know so I can address it.

Answer (score 1):

Tidied up:

```
 dicts=[]
 for item in self.info:
        tempdic={} # must create a new dictionary inside the loop
        tempdic['title'] = str(item['title'])
        tempdic['desc'] = str(item['desc'])
        dicts.append(tempdic)
```

And further

```
 dicts=[]
 for item in self.info:
        tempdic={'title': str(item['title'], 'desc': str(item['desc']}
        dicts.append(tempdic)
```

And further

```
dicts = [{'title' : str(x['title']), 'desc' str(x['desc'])} for x in self.info)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(self.info)):
    dicts.append({
        'title': str(self.info[i]['title']),
        'desc': str(self.info[i]['desc'])
    })
```